# Как добавить в гит конфигурационные файлы?

Tags: git

Вопрос в следующем. У меня есть файл, в котором прописан массив конфигураций. Я хочу добавить туда список ключей, которые можно конфигурировать, а значения будут подставляться индивидуально для каждой площадки.
Мне нужно добавить файл в гит с ключами, но без значений, закомитить, а после этого сделать так, чтобы этот файл больше не отслеживался.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая последовательность команд позволит мне это сделать?

Comment: Никакая. Добавляйте в git пример конфига

Comment: Я задавал вопрос с подобной ситуацией - там есть ответ, правда, я им так и не воспользовался.

Comment: Хранить конфиги в git не положено. А если ключи секретные, то хранить их в git вообще категорически противопоказано

Comment: Пользуйтесь правильными инструментами, а именно чем-то типа *ansible*. Git тут -- плохое решение.

Answer (score 2):

Это довольно рискованное мероприятие. Часто используют другой подход:

Допустим, файл конфигурации называется `config.json`. Этот файл добавляют в `.gitignore` сразу. Затем создают отдельно файл с заглушками и называют его `config-template.json`. Его добавляют в репозиторий.

В этом случае сценарий следующий: пользователь клонирует репозиторий, из шаблона `config-template.json` создает свой `config.json`, поскольку он уже игнорируется гитом, то никогда не получает его в списке добавленных или изменённых.

Answer (score -3):

Добавить, запушить, а потом внести в .gitignore.

Comment: И ничего не выйдет

Comment: @AlexeyTen я подозревал.

Comment: Вполне выйдет, если запушить не реальные значения, а заглушки, после чего установить реальные значения и заставить Git считать файл неизменённым: `git update-index --assume-unchanged FILE_HERE`