# Gitignore - не игнорирует файл в репозитории

Tags: git

Есть эталонный файл `user_config.ini` он должен быть в репозитории и для других пользователей он должен быть неизменим т.е. при клоне, он должен загрузиться один раз пользователю, и сразу попасть в игнор, чтобы потом пользователь мог локально изменить этот файл но при дальнейших коммитах и пуллах, чтобы этот файл не затрагивался.

1) Я первым делом удалил этот файл из репозитория: `git rm --cached user_config.ini`
2) Я добавил его в гитигнор и закомитил/запушил измения, но к сожалению `user_config.ini` не запушился т.к. он в игноре, согласно гиту так и должно быть.

Но если файл УЖЕ в репозитории, как сейчас, то он просто в игнор не добавляется. Получается что игнорить его нет возможности.

3) В этом случае я воспользовался не гит игнором, а `git update-index --skip-worktree user_config.ini` но так не удобно, ведь каждому пользователю прийдётся у себя в гите прописывать эту команду. Также если пользователь команду не пропишет, то файл запушиться и испортит мой эталонный файл.

Подскажите, как решить данную ситуацию?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить в гит конфигурационные файлы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1085362/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Comment: т.е. методом переименования файла только? Я думал, что есть более универсальное решение...

Comment: Там ко второму ответу есть полезный комментарий.

Comment: Да, но и мой вариант в этом вопросе работает. Основной ньюанс именно в том, чтобы это был какой-то автоматизированный процесс, чтобы пользователи у себя локально вручную не прописывали `git update-index --assume-unchanged user_config.ini`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [git и конфигурационные файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416219/git-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)